# How do I force automatic subtitles on a youtube video to play on youtube.com?

Tags: youtube, subtitles, editing

How do I force automatic subtitles on a youtube video to play on youtube.com? Not embedded. Can you give me a full line of URL to show me what code I need to add. My youtube video is in English, my family are French & old & can easily click a link from Facebook messenger or other messengers but get confused if choosing a language manually. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, YouTube does not expose a URL parameter for subtitles like they do for timestamps and other such features.

If you wish to automatically enable subtitles on *every* video they watch, I would suggest [changing the playback settings](https://www.youtube.com/account_playback) for their browser(s).

Here's a screenshot for a visual example of what that would look like:

[image: Changing the browser caption settings. The relevant settings are highlighted by a red box around them.]

**Note**: The language of the automatically generated captions would be determined by YouTube in this case. Changing the above option also requires them to use the same browser whenever they watch videos for it to take effect. (It is configured separately for each browser and computer).